# Como organizar resultados da BDados

Tags: mysql

### Olá, estou fazendo um site de filme e gostaria de uma ajuda nessa parte.

Após conseguir conexão com a BD, quero que cada registro aparece dentro da *grid* que fiz.

Vou explicar melhor com fotos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada filme tem seu registro contendo cada informação que desejo manipular.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acima mostra como eu chamo meu *script* PHP que contem a conexão com BD.
    porém ele mostra os 2 registro no mesmo local, 
    queria que o filme 1 fosse no local do 1 e assim por diante. segue a *grid* do *layout*!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o arquivo PHP

```
<?php 
$conecta = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or print (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("bd", $conecta) or print(mysql_error()); 


 $filmes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filmes");
    while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($filmes)){

         echo $dados['nome'] . "<br>";
         echo $dados['sinopse'] . "<br>";
         echo $dados['categoria'] . "<br>";

    }


?>
```

Comment: Gustavo, o SO não aceita tags PHP, tente reproduzir seu exemplo no seguinte site: http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: Esse último trecho seria seu get.php?

Comment: sim, ele é basicamente pra conexão.

Comment: Então você pode montar sua estrutura dentro do while...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da forma que está fazendo, terá de concatenar o HTML dentro do arquivo php.

```
<?php 
$conecta = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or print (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("bd", $conecta) or print(mysql_error()); 

$filmes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filmes");
$size = 0;
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($filmes)){
     if($size == 0)
         echo "<ul>";
     echo "<li>";
     echo $dados['nome'] . "<br>";
     echo $dados['sinopse'] . "<br>";
     echo $dados['categoria'] . "<br>";
     echo "</li>";
     if($size == 2)
         echo "</ul>";
     $size++;
     $size = $size == 3 ? 0 : $size;
}
?>
```

E no seu HTML, altere para:

```
<div><?php include("get.php"); ?></div>
```

Comment: WOW, kkkk, parece magica!, funcionou cara, perfeitamente! muito obrigado.

Comment: Editei para ele exibir 3 filmes por linha e então adicionar uma nova linha.